# DateListPlot not working with a Tooltipped Association

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, tooltip

The following fails to work

```
assoc = <|DatePlus[Today, -3] -> 1, DatePlus[Today, -2] -> 2|>;
labels = <|DatePlus[Today, -3] -> "Some tasks", 
   DatePlus[Today, -2] -> "Some more tasks."|>;
final = Merge[{assoc, labels}, (Tooltip[First[#], Last[#]]) &]
DateListPlot[final, Mesh -> Full, Joined -> False]
```

> [image]

yet when the tooltips are removed, it does:

> [image]

Comment: From the documentation *wapper* must contain the date and the value. Code above only wraps the value. Try `final =
 KeyValueMap[Tooltip[{#1, #2["Value"]}, #2["Label"]] &]@
  Merge[{assoc, 
    labels}, <|"Value" -> First[#], "Label" -> Last[#]|> &]` .

Comment: @Edmund: That answers the question.